API can't access to private endpoints (403 Forbidden) even though user is authenticated
I think what is wrong is my authenticationFilter.
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String token = getTokenFromRequest(request);
    final String username;
    if (token == null) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    username = jwtService.getUsernameFromToken(token);
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (jwtService.isTokenValid(token, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails,
                    null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

The userdetails get added to the security context as expected but then the doFilter messes it up. What I might be doing wrong?
This is the SecurityConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authProvider;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .csrf(csrf->
                csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authRequest ->
                authRequest
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(sessionManager ->
                sessionManager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
    }
}

I'm always getting a 403 Forbidden response in Postman.
Any ideas what might be wrong?
Debugged but I cannot find the issue. I'm missing something (probably stupid) but cannot find it.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT:
Those are the logs with LogLevel DEBUG:
2024-07-01T11:50:08.830-07:00 DEBUG 15809 --- [WorkLogAPI] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/v1/demo/
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.password,u1_0.role,u1_0.username from wluser u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
2024-07-01T11:50:33.405-07:00 DEBUG 15809 --- [WorkLogAPI] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/v1/demo/
2024-07-01T11:50:33.442-07:00 DEBUG 15809 --- [WorkLogAPI] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-07-01T11:50:33.443-07:00 DEBUG 15809 --- [WorkLogAPI] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-07-01T11:50:33.444-07:00 DEBUG 15809 --- [WorkLogAPI] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access


Hello, Just to be sure with the debugger, you get to the end of the doFilterInternal method and you can see that auth.isAuthenticated() is set to True ? You can also modify spring security to get more logs about filter chain by setting log level to TRACE. Exemple

debug logs are showing that you are calling the endpoint without being authenticated - hence the 403. You need to go through the doFilterInternal method with a debugger and see why the authentication is not set

@JAsgarov evaluating the SecurityContextHolder gives the principal with the correct data from the user, and authenticated = true at the end of doFilterInternal. The sessionId is null tho, is it supposed to be null?

sessionId is null, because you have set session to be stateless SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS (no session). But you should be using some kind of jwt token header/cookie to authenticate and your jwtAuthenticationFilter should set the authentication object

The token is being passed properly to the request since I'm getting all data from the token correctly and SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken) is also being done since at the end of doFilterInternal, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() evaluates as true. Am I not looking in the right place?

please delete the entire JWTFilter, handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous, and there is a reason this is not built into spring security. Please dont just google and read a blog, read the actual docs and dont use JWTs what they are not meant to be used for. Read the docs.

This question is similar to: Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security Intercepts exceptions I don't want it to. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You get 403, because your /error endpoint is not permitted. If you open the endpint you will see the actual reason.

@dur thanks por pointing this out because it solved it. Didn't know it was a problem with /error endpoint so I did not search in that direction. Now I'm curious in why not having permitted /error affects a request that should not give any.

Thanks to @dur I got this solved!
I had my /error endpoint secured so 403 was being responded.
Adding .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll() to my securityFilterChain solved the issue.
Sorry for all of you that saw a similar question to Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security Intercepts exceptions I don't want it to
Honestly I didn't know this was the issue so I did not do any research in that direction.
Thanks to all of those that invested time in helping!!
Now I'm curious as why this happens. Guess I'll do some research about this now.
